# Javascript: Am I using onreadystatechange properly?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Bare in mind I am **very** new to JavaScript syntax, so please have patience.

I'm trying to use multiple `onreadystatechange`'s as promises to catch what I return from express, but every time I do, both of them are getting called. Here is my code:

```
var ready = function(){

    xhr.open('GET', 'getallbeertypes');
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        var parent = document.getElementById('recipes');
        var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

        if(xhr.status == 200){
            var beerTypes = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            //loop through beerTypes to append a button to each list item
            for (var beer = 0; beer < beerTypes.length; beer++){
                //create necessary elements
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                var button = document.createElement('BUTTON');

                //set text content to list item
                li.textContent = beerTypes[beer].alias;

                //append list item to button
                button.appendChild(li);

                // add onclick attribute
                button.setAttribute("name", beerTypes[beer]._id);
                button.setAttribute("onclick", "moreInfo(this.getAttribute('name'))");

                //append button to document fragment
                docfrag.appendChild(button);
            }

            //display on DOM element
            parent.appendChild(docfrag);
        }else{
            // console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            var header = document.createElement('h1');
            header.textContent = "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            docfrag.appendChild(header);
            parent.appendChild(header);
        }
    }
}
ready();
```

So the above section of code works, and it displays each JSON object as a button in a list of items. When the button is clicked, the following function is supposed to run:

```
var moreInfo = function(_id){
    xhr.open('GET', '/getuserrecipes/' + _id);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        console.log("is this running?");
        console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the `onclick` attribute should only run the `moreInfo` function.

Whenever I click one of the buttons, the `else` statement in the `ready` function is somehow running and displays `Something went wrong. Please try again later` on the screen.

The only connection I can make is the `onreadystatechange`, but I don't really know if that's it.

How/why is the other function even being called and How can I stop it? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for the state of the request. To do that, use readyState property. There are 5 states, integers from 0 to 4, and you want the last one, which is 4.

something like this:

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
 ...
}
```

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) example.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for dealing with my novice questions.